# iPhone Address Book Search

Tags: iphone, ios, abaddressbook

I want to create an inline address book search on my application.  Basically I have a UITextField and I want it so that when you start typing text in, it will bring up search results from your Address Book, and can auto-complete what you're typing when you click it.  If you look in the SMS or Mail application, typing in the "To" field when sending a message is exactly what I want.

I've looked through Apple's Address Book Programming Guide and the closest thing it has is ABPeoplePickerNavigationController.  But this brings up a new view controller, which is not what I want.  So my question is, is there an iOS API that allows me to use this search functionality?  Or do I have to write my own?

**tl;dr** How do I mimic Apple's Address Book search function directly in a text field?

Answer (score 2):

This [demo project](https://github.com/mabundo/ButtonPeoplePicker) includes source code to perform an inline address book search from a UISearchBar.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the ABAddressBookCopyPeopleWithName API.